# Where does Jenkins save build parameters for a particular job?

Tags: jenkins

You can configure Jenkins to take parameters for a job, such as default values for a parameter:

[image]

Since it can take default value for parameters (my interest is password parameters in particular), where and how are they stored?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In jenkins 2+ its in `$JENKINS_HOME/jobs/<JOB_NAME>/config.xml` under the `hudson.model.ParametersDefinitionProperty` tag